# How can all files suddenly have become access-denied?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, troubleshooting, user-accounts

I'm having major trouble with my desktop, which is running Windows XP Professional. All the files have become access-denied overnight. I unchecked the file sharing option, I tried resetting the user in security settings, but still no luck.

Anyone have any other tricks to try?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to [retake ownership](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421) of your files.